# Heex form_for with extra fields?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Suppose we have this:

```
<%= form_for @conn, Routes.contracts_path(@conn, :ar_check), fn f -> %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This results in a form such as

```
<form action="..." method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

How can I change this such that the finished product looks like this?

```
<form action="..." method="post" data-test="foo">
   ...
</form>
```

It won't compile when I try to add it to the template line with the `form_for`. And while it will compile if I put it in the `<% end %>`, it won't run (and even if it did, that's confusing)

If I add it anywhere else, it works fine, for example `<%= submit "Check",  class: "btn btn-success mb-3", "data-test": "check_button" %>`

Is there a solution besides putting a `<span data-test="foo">` around the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found an answer after some trial and error:

`<%= form_for @conn, Routes.contracts_path(@conn, :ar_check), ["data-test": "foo"], fn f -> %>`

seems to be what I was looking for.